# JEST in GraalVM

Tags: jestjs, graalvm

I have an application that uses GraalVM to execute JavaScript code.  The JavaScript code can access Java objects which means it must execute in the GraalVM environment.  These tests can not be executed in Node.js or in a browser.  I am looking for documentation on how to execute tests using JEST in GraalVM. Or JEST in a standalone JavaScript environment that is not Node or a browser.

Does anyone know if this documentation exists?  Or how to do this?

Comment: Mind if I ask why "These tests can not be executed in Node.js"? GraalVM does provide a node.js implementation which can also interop with Java.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question from BoriS and add further information.

The Node.js implementation in GraalVM can not be called from a GraalVM Context within Java, and you can not call a Java application that creates said Context from Node.js without going to the command line. And, going to the command line will not work for us. For what we are trying to accomplish, Node.js can not be apart of the equation.  We have JavaScript being executed with a Java application using GraalVM's Context which has access to some of our Java objects.

After watching the [Architecture video](https://jestjs.io/docs/architecture), and digging through the JEST code base.  You can use JEST if your application is Node.js based and executes within that environment.  HOWEVER, if you have a standalone Java application that creates a GraalVM Context and executes JavaScript within that Context, you can not use Node.js.

Interestingly, JEST uses Jasmine to do the execution of the test. Jasmine used to have a CommonJS CDN. Though, I think Jasmine has been migrated to be more intertwined with Node.js. I am still digging around for the CommonJS CDN for the latest version of Jasmine.

This has become an issue for a small set of applications because the majority of the community that builds JavaScript applications either executes the JavaScript in the browser, or in Node.js.  There is a very small part of that community that executes JavaScript within a Java application using GraalVM's Context.